# Create Envelope from a template does not give error if recipient you send is more than the template roles

Tags: docusignapi

For example I have a template with 3 signers.

Signer1
Signer2
Signer3

In my call to EnvelopeApi.createEnvelope, I put 4 Signers.
Signer1
Signer2
Signer3
Signer4

Since Signer4 does not exist on the template, it should give an error saying that signer4 does not exist on the template.

Also if you put only 2 Signers, it allows it to create the Envelope.
Notice that the solution for this is to through the Advance Settings of the role but the error for this is not clear. it just says "The email address for the recipient is invalid..."

I'm thinking of a solution where I check first the template Roles of the template and compare it to the signers provided before creating the Envelope so that I have a more precise error message.

Or do I only have to set a property or there is already a function in the sdk for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reaching out to us. There could be a few things going on here -- are you by chance using Composite Templates?

The reason that I ask is that certain DocuSign functionalities actually allow for you to add / redact signer details at will. In some cases template roles that do not have a name / email applied to them on send can be automatically dropped. The opposite is also true where additional recipient details can be fed in to add signers to said envelope in the same call.

We can certainly have a closer look at what's going on, but we would need to see the API logs generated from your envelope send in order to diagnose the issue. (Please don't post them here).

Feel free to open a support ticket at support.docusign.com or send me an email at matt.king@docusign.com and we can have a case generated for you.

Regards,

Matt

DocuSign Developer Support